# Как узнать SSID подключённого WI-FI с помощью Python?

Tags: python-3.x, wifi, subprocess

Нужно узнать SSID WIFI, к которому подключён компьютер и сделать это на языке Python.
Пробовал с помощью  `subprocess.check_output()`:

```
import subprocess

Interfaces = str(subprocess.check_output('netsh wlan show interfaces'))
print(Interfaces)
```

И при выводе получается строка, в которой и содержится SSID, то есть выходит строка с определёнными данными о подключении, и в этой строке есть пункт: `"SSID: "Сам SSID"\r\n"`. Исходя из этого, SSID можно получить, просто "выловив" от туда этот пункт, но есть несколько нюансов и трудностей, что делает этот способ не практичным.

Если кто-нибудь знает методы лучше - будьте добры поделитесь опытом. Если не знаете  - помогите со способом, указанном выше.

**Заранее спасибо.**

Comment: Не проверял, но на английском SO пишут про `iwgetid -r`

Comment: по моему, неплохой способ: просто выдать команду и пропарсить ответ

Comment: @S.H. Тогда можете пожалуйста подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: @ValleraProgrammist, но вы же сами пишете > но есть несколько нюансов и трудностей, что делает этот способ не практичным - то есть, как я понимаю, вы уже попробовали этот способ и он вам не понравился...